# AOSP ROM for Samsung Grand duos GT-i9082 Error loading kernel

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I want to build an AOSP ROM for the Samsung Grand duos GT-i9082. I have the kernel, and device tree in cyanogenmod and AOSP sources. After compiling, I got the following error:

```
Install: out/host/linux-x86/bin/minigzip
Target ram disk: out/target/product/i9082/ramdisk.img
Target boot image: out/target/product/i9082/boot.img
Error: could not load kernel 'out/target/product/i9082/kernel'
make: *** [out/target/product/i9082/boot.img] Error 1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have a file named 'kernel' in out/target/product/i9082/  ? is not, then your kernel is not being copied/compiled

Comment: nop, there is no such a file name kernel. How do i compile kernel file for my device?

Comment: There are several ways for you to get the kernel into that directory. Compiling is only one of them. I suggest you to ask/search a separate question for that.Generic as possible.

Comment: can you please tell me , how can i do this.?

Answer (score 0):

This reply is a bit late, but it looks as if you don't have a file named "kernel", in that folder.
If you want to get that kernel, you can either:

1. Compile it from source
2. Extract it from boot.img

1.
If you have any other devices search them up. You will find your kernel, it's usually on Github, or the manufacturer's website.
Here are some common places to get the source code for your kernel.

```
LG: http://opensource.lge.com/index

Samsung: http://opensource.samsung.com/

HTC: https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads

OnePlus: https://github.com/OnePlusOSS

Motorola: https://github.com/MotorolaMobilityLLC
```

I can't give you a guide here on how to compile, because every device is different.
You're going to have to do a lot of research! it's worth it in the end, it took me weeks to figure out how to compile the kernel for my device.

2. Extract the kernel from boot.img (easier)

This guide: [Unpack Repack boot.img (Kernel) Files And Modify Ramdisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1477845)
will help you accomplish this.
If you can't figure this out, then you probably shouldn't be trying to do this.